# How on div hover make other div's image animate

Tags: html, css, layout

guys so basically I'm a bit stuck, the deal is that, the div that i need to hover on is under the div which image i need to trigger, I have no idea how to do that, and i need to do this with css. Simply it is layout with floats to left, so changing positions is hard form me. Any ideas?
here html code

```
<div id="layout">
    <div id="zydra"><img src="1blokopav.jpg"></div>
    <div id="zalia"> </div>
    <div id="melyna"></div>
    <div id="geltona"></div>
    <div id="orandzine"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <div id="ruda"></div>
    <div id="raudona"></div>  
    <div id="balta"></div>
</div>
```

need to hover on div which has id of melyna to trigger div of zydra id image
all of divs are given float left and some kind of width and height, it's simple color block layout, would love to hear your guys suggestions and if there is no way, how to move my div which contains image to bottom that it won't change layout

Comment: You can do it with css only if you move `#zydra` from first to last. Then you can access it like `#zalia:hover ~ #zydra { ... }` and so on.

Comment: CSS = Cascading Style Sheets . it goes from TOP to BOTTOM . not the other way around . you cannot access previous or parent element with CSS

Comment: okay so can i move my picture down the divs, and somehow attach it to div? so that when it moves, image is in the divs center?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xeVnJ310 here is my full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to rearrange DIVs inside #layout *upside down* and let the **flex css** arrange it back for you. like this:

**Edited**

```css
#layout {
  display: flex;
  /*this property will normalize the layout*/
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
#layout div {
  flex: 1 0 20%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#layout div#melyna:hover ~ div>img {
  opacity: .5;
  height: 5px;
  width: 15px;
}
#layout div:nth-child(n+5) {
  flex: 1 0 33.3%;
  background-color: lime;
}
div>img {
  transition: 2s all linear;
}
```

```html
<!--here you have to arrange back forward-->
<div id="layout">
  <div id="zalia"></div>
  <div id="melyna">hover me</div>
  <div id="geltona"></div>
  <div id="orandzine"></div>
  <!--clear: both-->
  <div id="ruda"></div>
  <div id="raudona"></div>
  <div id="balta"></div>
  <div id="zydra">
    <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg" width="100%" height="100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great explanation, but somehow it doesnt reverse, maybe because i have more divs that i didnt include in this code, and there are float clears as well?

Comment: Hi i updated the code already, basically in flex i wont use clear:both. 
Please review that one and try to play with flex also, it is great :)